# Why doesn't interfaces implement methods and override them?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I already read [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) of research effort required to post a SO question. I am ashamed again to post this question to a pile of million questions. But I still don't get the idea of interfaces in java. They have unimplemented methods and then defined for every class in which they are implemented. I searched about it. Interfaces were used to support multiple inheritance in java and also to avoid (Deadly) Diamond Death of inheritance. I also came across Composition vs Inheritance and that inheritance is not for code reuse and its for polymorphism. So when I have a common code as a class to extend it will not be supported due to multiple inheritance which gives the option to use Interfaces(Correct me if I am wrong). I also came across that its not possible in most cases to define a generic implementation. So what is the problem in having a common definition (not a perfect generic implementation) of the interface method and then Override it wherever necessary and why doesn't java support it. Eg. When I have 100 classes that implements an interface 70 of them have a common implementation while others have different implementation. Why do I have to define the common method in interface over 70 classes and why can't I define them in Interface and then override them in other 30 classes which saves me from using same code in 70 classes. Is my understanding of interfaces wrong?

Comment: What is an interface? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Java 8 supports default implementations for interface methods.

Comment: yes you can do that in Java 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, an interface in Java (as of Java 7) has no code. It's a mere definition, a contract a class must fulfill.

> So what is the problem in having a common definition (not a perfect
>   generic implementation) of the interface method and then Override it
>   wherever necessary and why doesn't java support it

Yes you can do that in Java, just not with interfaces only. Let's suppose I want from this `Example` interface to have a default implementation for `method1` but leave `method2` unimplemented:

```
interface Example {
   public void method1();
   public String method2(final int parameter);
}

abstract class AbstractExampleImpl implements Example {
    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // Implement
    }
}
```

Now classes that want to use this `method1` default implementation can just extend `AbstractExampleImpl`. This is more flexible than implementing code in the interface because if you do so, then all classes are bound to that implementation which you might not want. This is the advantage of interfaces: being able to reference a certain behavior (*contract*) without having to know how the class actually implements this, for example:

```
List<String> aList = MyListFactory.getNewList();
```

`MyListFactory.getNewList()` can return any object implementing `List`, our code manipulating `aList` doesn't care at all because it's based on the interface.

---

> What if the class that uses interface already is a Sub-class. Then we
>   can't use Abstract class as multiple inheritance is not supported

I guess you mean this situation:

```
class AnotherClass extends AnotherBaseClass
```

and you want to extend `AbstractExampleImpl` as well. Yes, in this case, it's not possible to make `AnotherClass` extend `AbstractExampleImpl`, but you can write a wrapped inner-class that does this, for example:

```
class AnotherClass extends AnotherBaseClass implements Example {
    private class InnerExampleImpl extends AbstractExampleImpl {
        // Here you have AbstractExampleImpl's implementation of method1
    }
}
```

Then you can just internally make all `Example` methods being actually implemented by `InnerExampleImpl` by calling its methods.

---

> Is it necessary to have the interface in AnotherClass?

I guess you mean `AnotherClass implements Example`. Well, this is what you wanted: have `AnotherClass` implement `Example` with some default implementation as well as extend another class, or I understood you wrong. Since you cannot extend more than one class, you have to implement the interface so you can do

```
final Example anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
```

Otherwise this will not be possible.

> Also for every class that implements an interface do I have to design
>   an inner class?

No, it doesn't have to be an inner class, that was just an example. If you want multiple other classes have this default `Example` implementation, you can just write a separate class and wrap it inside all the classes you want.

```
class DefaultExampleImpl implements Example {
   // Implements the methods
}

class YourClass extends YetAnotherClass implements Example {
    private Example example = new DefaultClassImpl();

    @Override
    public void method1() {
          this.example.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public String method2(final int parameter) {
          return this.example.method2(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the class that uses interface already is a Sub-class. Then we can't use Abstract class as multiple inheritance is not supported. @m0skit0

Comment: @xtreak sounds like a bad object hierarchy

Comment: Thanks I get it. I can use a method in AnotherClass that instantiates an InnerExampleImpl. Is it necessary to have the interface in AnotherClass? Also for every class that implements an interface do I have to design an inner class? @m0skit0

Comment: +1 In java 8, interfaces can have default implementations for methods.

Comment: Its available in java 8 @m0skit0 . But thanks for the insight.

Comment: @xtreak I didn't know that too, but Java 8 is not released yet, so *for now* that's not possible in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an **abstract class** to **implement** that interface, and make your those classes **inherit** that **abstract class**, that should be what you want.

Comment: You are suggesting to make the class as an interface? What if I have the class that implements the interface already as a sub-class.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you add a new abstract class implements your interface, in this abstract class you provide with the common implementation. Then in your 100 classes (all inherit this abstract class), you can make 30 of them override that implementation while others just stay using that common implementation.

Comment: What if the class that implements the interface is already a sub-class. The abstract class can't be used due to multiple inheritance @Paul

Comment: No, that's not a problem because it's not the case of 'multiple inheritance'. This is the beauty of interface's flexibility, implements doesn't conflict with extends at all. You can have a class extends another class (inheritance) while it implements many interfaces at the same time.

Comment: For the situation your worry about, I think @m0skit0 is already covered in his answer and comments :)

Answer (score 0):

A non abstract class that implements and interface needs to implement all the methods from the interface. A abstract class doesn't have to implement all the methods but cannot initiated. If you create abstract class in your example that implements all the interface methods except one. The classes that extend from these abstract class just have to implement the one not already implemented method.

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritance and we have interfaces to do them. So when I need to use two classes I use a class and an interface. What if I need two classes and multiple inheritance?

Comment: Do single inheritance multiple times: `class A implements I1{}
class B extends class A implements I2{}`

Answer (score 0):

The Java interfaces could have been called *contracts* instead to better convey their intent. The declarer promise to provide some functionality, and the using code is guaranteed that the object provides that functionality.

This is a powerful concept and is decoupled from *how* that functionality is provided where Java is a bit limited and you are not the first to notice that.  I have personally found that it is hard to provide "perfect" implementations which just need a subclass or two to be usable in a given situation. Swing uses adapters to provide empty implementations which can then be overrides as needed and that may be the technique you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the funda of interface first. Which is

- It is use to provide tight coupling means tight encapsulation
- It helps us to hide our code from the external environment i.e. from other class
- Interface should have only definition and data which is constant
- It provide facility to class open for extension. Hence it cannot be replace by the any other class in java otherwise that class will become close for extension. which means class will not be able to extend any other class.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the interface is to create a series of methods that are abstract enough to be used by different classes that implement them. The concept is based on the DRY principle (Don't repeat yourself) the interface allows you to have methods like run() that are abstract enough to be usuable for a game loop, a players ability to run,

Comment: When I use the interface with a common code and override it when necessary it aids the DRY principle even more. Whats the point in having a common code being defined 70 times doesn't it violate DRY?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are struggling with the concept of Object Oriented Design more than anything.  In your example above where you state you have `100` classes and `70` of them have the same method implementation (which I would be stunned by).  So given an interface like this:

```
public interface Printable
{    
     void print();
}
```

and two classes that have the "same" implementation of `print`

```
public class First implements Printable
{  
   public void print()  
   {  
         System.out.println("Hi");
   }  
}
public class Second implements Printable
    {  
       public void print()  
       {  
             System.out.println("Hi");
       }  
    }
```

you would instead want to do this:

```
public abstract class DefaultPrinter implements Printable  
{  
     public void print()  
     {  
         System.out.println("Hi");
     }  
}
```

now for `First` and `Second`

```
public class First extends DefaultPrinter 
{  
}
public class Second extends DefaultPrinter
{  
}
```

Now both of these are still `Printable` .  Now this is where it gets very important to understand how to properly design object hierarchies.  If something **IS NOT** a `DefaultPrinter` **YOU CANNOT AND SHOULD NOT** make the new class extend `DefaultPrinter`

Comment: Lets say the classes already extend a class like power i.e. First, Second. Some of them print in bold and some in italic while 70 of them underlined. I have a common interface that has PrintStyle() method. Why can't I have a common PrintStyle() method in interface and then overrride wherever necesaary with default implementation of underlined.

Comment: @xtreak because that isn't how java works.  I have detailed in my answer above how to accomplish what you need.

Comment: @xtreak and to be clear, an abstract class is a software interface, so you can put it in the abstract class like above.